# Decode JSON in perl

Tags: json, perl

I am trying to decode a simple JSON string in perl but it doesn't conform to JSON that I am used to.

The JSON is for Browshot and looks like:

```
{
  "52967":{
    "priority":"1",
    "status":"finished",
    "screenshot_url":"https://www.browshot.com/screenshot/image/52967?scale=1&key=MY_KEY",
    "id":"52967",
    "url": "http://www.google.com/",
    "size": "screen",
    "width": "1024",
    "height": "768",
    "request_time": "1312106111",
    "started": "1312258803994",
    "load": "1312258829461",
    "content": "1312258829661",
    "finished": "1312258829681",
    "instance_id": "10",
    "response_code": "200",
    "final_url": "http://www.google.com/",
    "content_type":"text/html",
    "scale": "1",
    "cost": "0",
    "referer": "",
    "post_data": "",
    "cookie": "",
    "delay": "5",
    "flash_delay": "10",
    "script": "",
    "shared_url": ""
  },
  "52969":{
    "priority":"1",
    "status":"finished",
    "screenshot_url":"https://www.browshot.com/screenshot/image/52969?scale=1&key=MY_KEY",
    "id":"52969",
    "url": "http://www.google.org/",
    "size": "screen",
    "width": 1024,
    "height": "768",
    "request_time": "1312106111",
    "started": "1312258803994",
    "load": "1312258829461",
    "content": "1312258829661",
    "finished": "1312258829681",
    "instance_id": "10",
    "response_code": "200",
    "final_url": "http://www.google.org/",
    "content_type":"text/html",
    "scale": "1",
    "cost": "0",
    "referer": "",
    "post_data": "",
    "cookie": "",
    "delay": "5",
    "flash_delay": "10",
    "script": "",
    "shared_url": ""
  },
  "52971":{
    "priority":"1",
    "status":"processing",
    "screenshot_url":"https://www.browshot.com/screenshot/image/52971?scale=1&key=MY_KEY",
    "id":"52971",
    "url": "http://www.google.de/",
    "size": "screen",
    "width": "1024",
    "height": "768",
    "request_time": "1312106111",
    "started": "1312258803994",
    "load": "1312258829461",
    "content": "1312258829661",
    "finished": "1312258829681",
    "instance_id": "10",
    "response_code": "200",
    "final_url": "http://www.google.de/",
    "content_type":"text/html",
    "scale": "1",
    "cost": "0",
    "referer": "",
    "post_data": "",
    "cookie": "",
    "delay": "5",
    "flash_delay": "10",
    "script": "",
    "shared_url": ""
  },
  "52970":{
    "priority":"1",
    "status":"finished",
    "screenshot_url":"https://www.browshot.com/screenshot/image/52970?scale=1&key=MY_KEY",
    "id":"52970",
    "url": "http://www.google.fr/",
    "size": "screen",
    "width": "1024",
    "height": "768",
    "request_time": "1312106111",
    "started": "1312258803994",
    "load": "1312258829461",
    "content": "1312258829661",
    "finished": "1312258829681",
    "instance_id": "10",
    "response_code": "200",
    "final_url": "http://www.google.fr/",
    "content_type":"text/html",
    "scale": "1",
    "cost": "0",
    "referer": "",
    "post_data": "",
    "cookie": "",
    "delay": "5",
    "flash_delay": "10",
    "script": "",
    "shared_url": ""
  },
  "52968":{
    "priority":"1",
    "status":"finished",
    "screenshot_url":"https://www.browshot.com/screenshot/image/52968?scale=1&key=MY_KEY",
    "id":"52968",
    "url": "http://www.google.com/",
    "size": "screen",
    "width": "1024",
    "height": "768",
    "request_time": "1312106111",
    "started": "1312258803994",
    "load": "1312258829461",
    "content": "1312258829661",
    "finished": "1312258829681",
    "instance_id": "10",
    "response_code": "200",
    "final_url": "http://www.google.com/",
    "content_type":"text/html",
    "scale": "1",
    "cost": "0",
    "referer": "",
    "post_data": "",
    "cookie": "",
    "delay": "5",
    "flash_delay": "10",
    "script": "",
    "shared_url": ""
  }
}
```

Normally I would use:

```
my $records = decode_json($JSON);

my @screens = @{ $records };
foreach my $f ( @screens ) {
  print "$f->{'screenshot_url'}|\n";
}
```

But this obviously does not work.

I'm sure it's simple but I must be missing the mark here and cannot find a solution, all help appreciated.

Comment: Try `my @screens = keys %$records`

Comment: There is a code sample available for Perl: https://browshot.com/api/documentation/code/perl/browshot_screenshot_list.pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over a hash, one normally iterates over the keys returned by `keys`.

```
for my $id (keys(%$records)) {
   my $record = $records->{$id};
   say $record->{screenshot_url};
}
```

Comment: Or all at once: `$records->{$id}{screenshot_url}`

Comment: thanks ikegami, the solution worked to print out one value, how would I then iterate over each value from the json?

Comment: Sorry User error - the real time JSON only had one array thank you that worked perfectly!